# Validating a jar made by Eclipse outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compilation

I have a Java application I've developed in Eclipse.  To package it into a .jar, I simply run File->Export->Runnable JAR file with copy jar files into sub folder selected.

For deployment, I turn over the compiled jar file along with my source code and the deployment team packages it up and deploys it to our systems.  One of the responsiblities of the deployment team is to verify that the source code that is turned over compiles into the binary that is turned over with it.  This is the only Java program the deployment team works with so they don't have Eclipse available to import my source code and validate it against what I provided them.  For the time being, they have just been taking my word for it, but that needs to change.  They will need to compile the code on their own and make sure it matches what I've given them.

How would they go about doing this?  I suppose one option is to get all of them up and running Eclipse, but that seems like an overkill.  Is there something they can run outside of Eclipse without having Eclipse installed to generate a jar file that they could validate is the same as what I've provided?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Use maven. [How to use Maven in my Java Project and Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072205/how-to-use-maven-in-my-java-project-and-why)

Comment: In a **professional** environment you absolutely do **not** rely on a build process that requires "custom handmade" installation of some IDE. Use a build system. End of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

First, how can they tell that what you supplied "matches"? That doesn't really make sense.

What they really want to do is to build their own deployment artifacts from your source. They can either set up Eclipse and use that as their build tool, or you and they can agree to use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle. These tools integrate with Eclipse, but they are designed to run stand-alone or as part of a tool like Hudson or Bamboo, which will perform build on a schedule or when a VCS is updated.

A client used Maven and Bamboo, along with the rest of the Atlassian suite, to handle enormous builds based on contributions of more than 100 developers. That included running JUnit tests, test coverage, and code quality tools.